# Why is my state not updating with fetched data in time for the useEffect to update my DOM with the new state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, react-hooks

I am new to using hooks in React. I am trying to fetch data when the component first mounts by utilizing useEffect() with a second parameter of an empty array. I am then trying to set my state with the new data. This seems like a very straightforward use case, but I must be doing something wrong because the DOM is not updating with the new state.

```
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);    

  useEffect(() => {
    const setTableDataToState = () => {
      fetchTableData()
        .then(collection => {
          console.log('collection', collection) //this logs the data correctly
          setTableData(collection);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    };

    setTableDataToState();
  }, []);
```

When I put a long enough timeout around the setTableData() call (5ms didn't work, 5s did), the accurate tableData will display as expected, which made me think it may be an issue with my fetch function returning before the collection is actually ready. But the console.log() before setTableData() is outputting the correct information-- and I'm not sure how it could do this if the data wasn't available by that point in the code.

I'm hoping this is something very simple I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: can you create a repl and share it.

Comment: You forgot to parse the json data coming back. Make sure you to use `.json()` to parse it. Also remember that parsing takes some time.

Comment: @Karrthik the repl would be non-functional as the API I'm using only works within a licensed environment of a somewhat obscure software program. Is there other info in particular that would be helpful beyond that?

Comment: @HenryLy thanks for the idea, but the fetch doesn't return json, it returns an array

Comment: @SaraHelba Please check this example https://repl.it/repls/MidnightblueNumbSystemadministrator

Answer (score 1):

The second argument passed to useEffect can be used to skip an effect.

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

They go on to explain in their example that they are using count as the second argument:

> "If the count is 5, and then our component re-renders with count still
> equal to 5, React will compare [5] from the previous render and [5]
> from the next render. Because all items in the array are the same (5
> === 5), React would skip the effect. That’s our optimization."

So you would like it to re-render but only to the point that the data changes and then skip the re-render.